# System.TypeException: Collection store exception

Tags: apex

Hi I am running a test class but one method fail giving:System.TypeException: Collection store exception putting ScenarioDumpJob.args_element into Map

Here is my mock class:

```
@IsTest
global class mockServiceTest implements WebServiceMock {
   global void doInvoke(
            Object stub, Object request, Map<String, Object> response,
            String endpoint, String soapAction, String requestName,
            String responseNS, String responseName, String responseType){
            if(request instanceof ScenarioDumpJob.args_element){
                ScenarioDumpJob.args_element responseElement = new ScenarioDumpJob.args_element();
                response.put('response_x', responseElement );
            }
            return;
        }
}
```

And my test Class method that is failing is:

```
private static testMethod void ScenarioDump2_CopyCoverMethodTest(){
        Test.setMock(WebServiceMock.class, new mockServiceTest());
        String[] item = new String[]{'item','0','-1','false'};
        ScenarioDumpJob.ScenarioDump2_Copy obj = new ScenarioDumpJob.ScenarioDump2_Copy();
        List<String> lst = new List<String>();
        lst=obj.runJob(item);
    }
```

Comment: From a quick Google, it seems like the underlying `response` collection will reject the wrong object type: is `ScenarioDumpJob.args_element` the right type?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that 2 web service methods are being called in your test class.
Below is a sample for 2 mock responses based on the method called.

```
public void doInvoke(
                Object stub,
                Object request,
                Map<String, Object> response,
                String endpoint,
                String soapAction,
                String requestName,
                String responseNS,
                String responseName,
                String responseType) {

    // Create response based on called method
    if(request instanceof DocuSignTK.CreateEnvelope_element){
        DocuSignTK.CreateEnvelopeResponse_element details = new DocuSignTK.CreateEnvelopeResponse_element();

        DocuSignTK.EnvelopeStatus createEnvelopeResult = new DocuSignTK.EnvelopeStatus();
        createEnvelopeResult.Status = 'Success';
        createEnvelopeResult.EnvelopeID = '1';

        details.CreateEnvelopeResult = createEnvelopeResult;

        response.put('response_x', details); 
    }else if(request instanceof DocuSignTK.RequestSenderToken_element){
        DocuSignTK.RequestSenderTokenResponse_element details = new DocuSignTK.RequestSenderTokenResponse_element();
        details.RequestSenderTokenResult = 'testtoken';
        response.put('response_x', details); 
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion since you could have scenarios like Lead conversion where multiple triggers fire in a single transaction with multiple callouts and you cannot just set one Mock Response. Thanks @GulShan